# Given a smooth even function $f(x)$, show the composition with $\sqrt x$ is right-differentiable at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

More specifically, I would like to show the following:
suppose $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $f \in C^\infty ( \mathbb{R})$, I want to show the function $h(x)=:f(\sqrt x)$ satisfies the property that $\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kh}{dx^k}(0) = \frac{1}{(2k)!}\frac{d^{2k}(f)}{dx^k}(0)$ , with the understanding that the derivatives of $h$ at $0$ is only the right derivative.

Naively because $f$ only has even power Taylor series expansion at $0$, we can just substitute $\sqrt x$ into the Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $0$ to see the above equality. However this doesn't seem rigorous at all when the function we are pre-composing is $\sqrt x$.

So how does one go about proving the equality? Or is there a theorem that justifies the substitution?

Edit: Perhaps we should even just begin by proving that $h$ is right-smooth.